# Vue-moment showing wrong time with timezone set

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, momentjs, inertiajs

Not sure what I am doing wrong. I have a laravel 8 application where I am storing my time in UTC with timestamp_no_timezone in postgresql. When I view the time in the database it is showing today's date with 13:45 as the time. When I use vue-moment and display the time with the timezone set to America/New_York it is still showing 1:45 PM and it should be 8:45 AM with the offset. What could I be missing? I have even done a console.log of the timezone from moment and it is showing America/New_York.

This is the expression that I am using:

`{{ [ timesheet.start, "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss" ] | moment("timezone", "America/New_York", "h:mm A") }}`

Answer (score 0):

Convert the stored dateTime to epoch while sending in response.

How you can convert dateTime to epoch there are many ways(send dateTime in epoch in response).

> Add in your Model

```
protected $casts = ['datetime_field' => 'timestamp']
```

> add this method in Laravel class from where you are sending response

```
    protected function toEpoch($datetime )
    {
        if (gettype($datetime) == 'string') {
            $datetime = new DateTime($datetime);
            return Carbon::instance($datetime)->format('U');
        } else if ($datetime instanceof Carbon) {
            return $datetime->format('U');
        } else if ($datetime != null) {
            return Carbon::instance($datetime)->format('U');
        }
      } 
    }
```

> In vue project

```
{{new Date(epoch*1000)}}
```